# How to add minutes to UTC time in C#

Tags: c#

Below is the sample code which convert utc time to `2014-12-20T20:13:11` format but i want to add number of minutes to above utc time suppose if i want to add `20 mins` my output should be `2014-12-20T20:33:11`  how to programm this please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyy-MM-dd");


        Console.WriteLine(currentDate + "T" + currentTime);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 string currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).ToString("s"));
```

Answer (score 3):

First you can and should do it in one expression:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ( "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Later if you want to add minutes you can do:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20).ToString ( "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```